# ssis job in sql server agent

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I created an SSIS package, which runs fine in Sql Server Business Intelligence.  The problem is when I try to schedule a job to run, I tested it and it says the exe does not exist in the directory and it lists the path to the directory where the exe is located.  The exe is obviously there, and the exe runs fine, it just doesn't like the package when I try to schedule a job.

The error that I can see in the job activity monitor is

Description: File/Process "FileName.exe" does not exist in the directory "DirectoryName" End Error

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

An SSIS package is not an EXE. The name is typically something like 'MyPackageName.dtsx'.  The package is interpreted & executed by the DTS utility running in conjunction with a SQL Server instance.

We use SQL Agent to run SSIS packages as a standard part of our application, so that itself shouldn't be a problem.  How do you have your SQL Agent job defined?

Comment: I realize that an SSIS package is not an exe.  In the SSIS package, it runs an exe.  What exactly do you mean how is it defined?  In the job step properties, the type is set to SQL Server Integration Services package

Comment: @user1202606, your problem description has skipped a number of details in your job setup. All we know is what you wrote. Having said that:

Does your Agent process have the necessary permissions to read/list   the folder where the EXE is? And does it have the necessary permissions to run arbitrary EXEs on the system?

Comment: it was a permissions issue, I solved it already.  Thanks for your responses, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either accept this answer or write your own and mark it as the accepted answer to your problem please =)